# can't connect to signalR from mobile device

Tags: signalr

I can't connect from mobile device:
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; he-il; GT-I9100T Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1 .
to signalR . in my MVC4 c# web site. keep getting error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection id is in the incorrect format.
```

Comment: Are you doing authentication of any sort?

Comment: I'm doing ajax post call to server with user name pass, there doing System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser, if OK I do reload in javascript: window.location.reload. in my JS every document.ready I try to connect to hub

Comment: We've updated the error message in later releases but the invalid operation exception you're getting is because your users are not authorizedd

Comment: I don't understand the answer. its a html web app using signalr, on many different devices it works but on android 2.3.3 it doesn't .I now my user is authorized cause he sees pages under authorized restriction.

Comment: If you're able to connect on other devices then that's definitely interesting... One thing you should verify is that you're authenticating BEFORE you start your SignalR connection.

Answer (score 0):

the reason was json error , I've added json2.js and it fixed the problem